# How to get the image from ImageView and convert it to a byte array to insert to a MySQL DB and retrieve from database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, bitmap

I have tried several ways but failed to save into the database. I want to try using Java, not PHP. please any suggestions or source code for inserting and retrieving images?

Comment: Which database are you referring to? is it mysql or sqlite or room?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Quality questions with detail oriented descriptions receive the best quality answers. Also, please be sure to post any relevant source code associated with this question. Here are tips to help you out: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Comment: @UmangBurman MYSQL

Comment: @JafrinaJui I'm sorry, you cannot do that via the java code. MYSQL is a part of server side and to deal with server side, you need server side language support.

Comment: @UmangBurman but i built an app and all kinds of insert,update,search,select is done by mysql query in android java class. I connect xampp server and successfully cad do these operations except image insetion. but i write code of image (blob to byte array and insert to db) it fail to insert. so i also tried by getting byte array from db and show another ImageView, it couldnot. and the column of the db table(blob) only contain 10B or 11B,,,

Comment: @UmangBurman I am weak in English. pls pardon me

Comment: Can you show your code for insertion please